# How to create menu in dnn that don't redirect to any page?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dotnetnuke-7

I use bootstrap for create skin in dotnetnuke .I use simple menu code that exist in bootstrap website. When i click on the menu item go to another page This item have number subitem .Can i create menu item in dnn that have no link to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a page in the menu, but not make it clickable by checking the "Disabled" box in Page Management.

[image]